# Why this mimir gateway ingress is not getting created?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-monitoring, grafana-mimir

-- A reverse proxy deployment that is meant to receive traffic for Mimir or GEM.
When enterprise.enabled is true the GEM gateway is deployed. Otherwise, it is an nginx.
Options except those under gateway.nginx apply to both versions - nginx and GEM gateway.

```
gateway:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    nameOverride: mimir-nginx
    hosts:
      - host: mimir-distributor.neu.internal.dev.(companyname).com
        paths:
          - path: /api/v1/push
            pathType: Prefix
    tls:
      - secretName: mimir-distributor-tls
        hosts:
          - mimir-distributor.neu.internal.dev.(companyname).com
  enabledNonEnterprise: true
  replicas: 1
```

secret exist and doest contain certificates, as far as i understand normal ingress will be depreciated soon so im trying to do one using gateway. But nothing gets created

Comment: Kindly refer to official [mimir setup using helm](https://grafana.com/docs/helm-charts/mimir-distributed/latest/get-started-helm-charts/). I was able to successfully deploy [mimir](https://i.imgur.com/6Izy6zd.png) following this document using [nginx ingress for mimir](https://i.imgur.com/akX8GP8.png). See [here](https://i.imgur.com/7OIvVpI.png)

However, an ingress YAML for Mimir, considering your requirements, would look something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/nQGBMYc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup mimir, follow this [document](https://grafana.com/docs/helm-charts/mimir-distributed/latest/get-started-helm-charts/) using.

```
helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo update![mimir](https://i.imgur.com/6Izy6zd.png)
```

The Helm chart at https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts is a publication of the source code at [**grafana/mimir**](https://github.com/grafana/mimir/tree/main/operations/helm/charts/mimir-distributed).

Install Mimir using the Helm chart:
`helm -n mimir-test install mimir grafana/mimir-distributed`

[image]

```
 kubectl -n mimir-test get pods
```

[image: here]

```
kubectl describe pod mimir-nginx -n mimir-test
```

[image: nginx ingress for mimir].
An ingress YAML for Mimir, considering your requirements, would look something like

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mimir-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mimir-distributor.neu.internal.dev.yourcompanyname.com
    secretName: mimir-distributor-tls
  rules:
  - host: mimir-distributor.neu.internal.dev.yourcompanyname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/v1/push
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: your-service-name
            port:
              number: 80
```